# How to create a List of Anonymous types?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a List of Anonymous types as shown below but I am making mistake somewhere

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{    
    var list = new[]
    {
        new { Number = i, Name = string.Concat("name",i) }
    };
}
```

E.g.

```
var o1 = new { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" }; 
var o2 = new { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" };

var list = new[] { o1, o2 }.ToList();
```

how to do the same at runtime?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: no error...but the collection is always 1

Comment: This is because you creating new list on every forloop

Comment: collection initialization is used , causes a new instance at every iteration.

Comment: @Rajeev Kumar, please see my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> no error...but the collection is always 1

That is because your are creating a **new list in each iteration**

You can try it like:

```
var list = new[] { new { Number = 0, Name = "Name1" } }.ToList(); //just to create a 
                                                  //list of anonymous type object
list.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new { Number = i, Name = string.Concat("name",i) });
}
```

Or one way to do that would be to use `List<Object>` like:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new { Number = i, Name = string.Concat("name",i) });
}
```

Or you can use [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) like

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                    .Select(i => new { Number = i, Name = "SomeName" })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: how to do the same at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Were you thinking of something like the following (using LINQ):

```
var anonList = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => new { 
        ID = i, 
        Name = String.Format("Name{0}", i)
    });
```

You could of course replace Enumerable.Range() with anything that give you a list to select from.

Answer (score 0):

You need a List object to store it.

```
List<Object> o = new List<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{    

    o.Add(new { Number = i, Name = string.Concat("name",i) });
}

o.Dump();
```

Comment: The intermediate list inside the loop is totally unnecessary. Furthermore, your code creates a list of arrays of anonymous types.

Comment: yup, you are right. Again, I don't really know  what he wants to achieve.

Comment: He wants to have a list with ten anonymous objects in it.

Comment: The question isn't vague. Your answer is wrong and you don't correct it despite being notified about it.

Comment: who knows he might need an array for each ?

Comment: Why would he? He didn't mention it at all - nothing in the question even hints at it. Now that you fixed the answer I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Define a list first then store the value in For loop

```
List<Object> NewList = new List<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            NewList.Add(
            { 
               new { Number = i, Name = string.Concat("name",i) }

            });
        }
```

Comment: The intermediate list inside the loop is totally unnecessary. Furthermore, your code creates a list of arrays of anonymous types.

Comment: He just like to downvote people because we wrap the original answer with an List<Object> collection.

Comment: @cherhan: You don't seem to get it. The OP wants a list of ten anonymous objects. You two guys are creating a list with ten arrays of anonymous objects where each array has one element.

Comment: No flaming but we added it before he modified the question.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks for explanation. I got your point. I hv updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 10)
{
    list.Add(new { Number = i, Name = string.Concat("name",i) });
    i++;
}
```